# Get a text field formated as xml body value

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, vb.net

I have a table where a column is stored in a xml format so it is possible do display it on other projects with formatted text.

But I need to convert it to a single line without tags.

I have tried to use value() method and nodes(), but didn't quite managed to make it work...

This is the example of the content of the column i want to format.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">    <head>      <title></title>      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />      <style type="text/css">p {font-family: sans-serif;font-size: 8.25pt;margin: 0px;}</style>    </head>    <body>      <p>VALUE I WANT TO GET </p>    </body>  </html>
```

```
SELECT Id, Description, Value FROM MyTable
```

Where Value is the column with stored xml..

Is there a way to get the body content without any tags in a single line?

THE COLUMN IS NOT XML TYPE BUT VARCHAR(MAX) TYPE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your HTML value always same format, please try following scripts together:

1. Converting HTML into supported format for querying with `value ()` and `node()`

```
    Declare @x nvarchar (4000) = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">    <head>      <title></title>      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />      <style type="text/css">p {font-family: sans-serif;font-size: 8.25pt;margin: 0px;}</style>    </head>    <body>      <p>VALUE I WANT TO GET </p>    </body>  </html>'

    select @x = replace (@x, 
                            '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> ',
                            ''
                        );

    SELECT @x = REPLACE(@x, 'xmlns=', 'xmlns:i=');

    --Print @x;
```

2. Actual select query on converted XML

```
    select  xmldata, 
            Cast (x2.c.query('data(body/p)') as nvarchar (100)) as HtmlBody
    From
        (select convert (xml, @x ) as xmldata) as x
            cross apply xmldata.nodes('html') as x2(c)
```

**Additional:**
Querying direct table, hope this would work if you replace `@temp` with your table name and column names accordingly

```
Declare @Temp table (ID bigint, xmlvalue nvarchar(4000) );
Declare @x nvarchar (4000) = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">    <head>      <title></title>      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />      <style type="text/css">p {font-family: sans-serif;font-size: 8.25pt;margin: 0px;}</style>    </head>    <body>      <p>VALUE I WANT TO GET </p>    </body>  </html>';

Insert into @Temp 
VALUES (101, @x);


select  x.*, 
        Cast (x2.c.query('data(body/p)') as nvarchar (100)) as HtmlBody
From    (
        select ID, CAST(REPLACE(
                        (replace (xmlvalue, 
                                '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> ',
                                '') ),
                        'xmlns=', 
                        'xmlns:i='
                        ) AS xml) as xmldata
        from @Temp
        ) as x
        CROSS APPLY xmldata.nodes('html') as x2(c)
go
```

If you think it's difficult to manager in future, create scalar function with same logic - Consider recommendations in terms of performance when using `custom scalar functions`

Comment: Besides the fact, that this can be achieved much simpler, I feel obliged to write against the hint *create scalar function with same logic*. Scalar functions are in almost any case very bad performers and should be avoided...

Comment: ... And casting the result of. query() to nvarchar will not resolve entities... You must use. value()...

Comment: Thanks for notifying that, it would appreciable, and helpful for us if you could share some test cases or further explanation.

Comment: I've already placed an answer myself. Did you check this out?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar to this: 
Language is VB.Net.

```
Dim XMLDoc As New XmlDocument
Dim dt As DataTable = GetData()  <-- GetData() is where you load the data using your query

XMLDoc.Load(dt.Rows(0).Item("Value").ToString)

Dim TextThatIWant As string = XMLDoc.SelectSingleNode("/html/body/p").InnerText
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
DECLARE @YourValue VARCHAR(MAX)=
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">    <head>      <title></title>      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />      <style type="text/css">p {font-family: sans-serif;font-size: 8.25pt;margin: 0px;}</style>    </head>    <body>      <p>VALUE I WANT TO GET </p>    </body>  </html>';

WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml')
SELECT CONVERT(xml,@YourValue,2).value('(/html/body/p/text())[1]','varchar(1000)');
```

The idea in short:

- We can not `CAST()` the string to XML, due to the `<!DOCTYPE>`, but we can use `CONVERT()` with the parameter `2`. This will return your string as XML.
- Against the XML we can use `.value()`
- As your XML declares a *default namespace* we declare this namespace using `WITH XMLNAMESPACES`

**Attention**: HTML is far not as strict as XML. If you cannot be sure, that your HTML is XHTML actually (which means, that it follows the much stricter rules of XML), it can be dangerous to rely on XML methods. Luckily the namespace points to xhtml...
If not, this might work in all your tests, but break in production at any time...